# How to properly update a custom serializable class

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm working for an update of an already released application that serializes some data into xml files, but now we have to update the class that is serialized (change a property to be a list of T instead of just T), but I want to be still able to read and old file, something like this :

```
public class Person 
{

    public int Age{ get; set;}

    public string Name{ get; set;}

    //public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Nickname { get; set; }

}

void Main()
{
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));


//   var p = new Person() { Age = 5, Name = "Jack", Nickname = "Thunder"};
//   
//   using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("Test.txt"))
//      serializer.Serialize(s,p);

     using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader("Test.txt"))
        serializer.Deserialize(s).Dump(); 
}
```

So I don't really know how to append the old plain string Nickname property to the updated Nickname property,

How would you address this?

Comment: if it is serialized as a `string` then you  can't do that.use linq to xml instead.

Comment: You can do it, if you write a custom serialisation method. However, I would name the new property Nicknames and mark the old property as obsolete so you can change your code everywhere. Also, run a conversion of your old serialised data and store the new object.

Comment: you mean implementing ISerializable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the old XML automatically compatible with the new class by adding the attribute [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) to the `Nickname` property:

```
[XmlElement]
public List<string> Nickname { get; set; }
```

Adding this attribute indicates that the `Nickname` property should be serialized as a sequence of elements without an outer wrapper element.  E.g. the following `Person`:

```
var person = new Person
{
    Age = 21,
    Name = "Richard",
    Nickname = new List<string>()
    {
        "Rick", 
        "Ricky",
        "Dick",
    },
};
```

Would be serialized as follows:

```
<Person>
  <Age>21</Age>
  <Name>Richard</Name>
  <Nickname>Rick</Nickname>
  <Nickname>Ricky</Nickname>
  <Nickname>Dick</Nickname>
</Person>
```

Since the old XML be structured identically but with no more than one  `<Nickname>` element, that element's value will be added to the list as its single entry when encountered during deserialization.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cKv3uN).

You could also change the name of the property to `Nicknames` and specify the old name be used for serialization by using [`[XmlElement("Nickname")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdsk9t4x.aspx):

```
[XmlElement("Nickname")]
public List<string> Nicknames { get; set; }
```

For more see [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx).